# Cross section, what is the only "ones" diameter suppose to be?

Tags: geometry

So there are two straws, like something you would drink with.

One has a diameter of: 36mm (a)
Another has a diameter of: 48mm (b)

Now I am suppose to swap those two for "another one" with the same cross section value. Here's what I have come up with.

In order to find the cross section value this is the formula.

CS: r^2*pi

a: 18^2*pi = 1017.87
b: 24^2*pi = 1809.55
Both of them are value of: 2826.55

Now the splitting them up in one with the same value of both which is 2826.55
I found out the diameter of the only "one" needs to be 60 in order to have the same value. So , CS: 30^2*pi = 2826.55 But I haven't figured the calculation, I guessed the number but how is it exactly calculated?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have done:
$$r^2\pi=2826.55\ ,\quad\hbox{so}\quad r=\sqrt{\frac{2826.55}{\pi}}=30\ .$$
But even easier, go back to the beginning:
$$18^2\pi+24^2\pi=r^2\pi$$
so
$$18^2+24^2=r^2$$
so
$$r=\sqrt{18^2+24^2}=30$$
and the diameter is $60$.